# Binding issues with knockout and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

**UPDATE**: The third bullet below ("so I tried the following" section) is the closest I have come to a fix. I *think* I basically need to 1) disable the button, 2) add ui-disable, 3) jqm refresh, all within the data-bind or model.

I am trying to get one of the knockout [demos](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html) to run with jqm in order to build something similar in my project. It mostly works except that the submit button <strike>does not disable</strike> goes disabled but does not appear grayed out if items = 0.

If you remove jqm, the example works fine and the button turns gray. I realize that jqm can conflict with knockout due to dom manipulation so I tried the following:

- Triggering style refresh in the model methods: `$('button').button();` or `$('.ui-page-active' ).page( 'destroy' ).page();`
- Starting the binding after `pageinit`. This broke the entire thing.
- As a test, I tried a data-bind to set ui-disable instead of disabling the button. It applies the class but jqm needs a refresh somehow. Can I put code into the data-bind to do the refresh?

  `<button data-bind="css: {'ui-disable': gifts().length > 0}" type='submit'>Submit</button>`

Here is the fiddle I have been using to troubleshoot this: http://jsfiddle.net/wtjones/wkEgn/

What am I missing?

```
    <form action='/someServerSideHandler'>
    <p>You have asked for <span data-bind='text: gifts().length'>&nbsp;</span> gift(s)</p>
    <table data-bind='visible: gifts().length > 0'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Gift name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th />
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind='foreach: gifts'>
            <tr>
                <td><input class='required' data-bind='value: name, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: price, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeGift'>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button data-bind='click: addGift'>Add Gift</button>
    <button data-bind='enable: gifts().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The model code:

```
var GiftModel = function(gifts) {
    var self = this;
    self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);

    self.addGift = function() {
        self.gifts.push({
            name: "",
            price: ""
        });       
    };

    self.removeGift = function(gift) {
        self.gifts.remove(gift);                
    };

    self.save = function(form) {
        alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.gifts));
        // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.gifts);
    };
};

var viewModel = new GiftModel([
    { name: "Tall Hat", price: "39.95"},
    { name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.00"}
]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// Activate jQuery Validation
//$("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });
```

Comment: I don't see your problem in the jsFiddle. Using the latest Chrome the Sumbit button is not clickable if I remove all the gifts...

Comment: You are correct but I didn't realize that because the mobile style doesn't change on the button. I updated the question to reflect that. Do I need to somehow bind a handler to refresh it?

Comment: I tried binding ui-disable as well. I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. If you change button properties via JS (or using KO to change these props), then you must call the refresh method to update visual styling.

```
$('button').button('refresh');
```

So I suggest to create custom binding instead of default `enable` that updates mobile button styling (if applied):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.mobileEnable = {
    update: function(el) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.enable.update.apply(el, arguments);
        $.fn.button && $(el).button('refresh');
    }
}
```

and...

```
<button data-bind='mobileEnable: gifts().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>
```

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkEgn/2/

Comment: I also came up with a similar fiddle but yours seems a bit cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/wtjones/BZ2C5/

What is this part?:
ko.bindingHandlers.enable.update.apply(el, arguments)`;

Comment: This line calls default `enable` binding callback (and enables/disables button even if you don't use jqm) before to update styling.

Comment: Thanks so much for this ! Be carefull, adding CLICK uses INIT instead of UPDATE: ko.bindingHandlers.click.init.apply(el, arguments);